# Hide content for mobile

Tags: php, jquery, css, media-queries

I've been trying to hide something that looks weird in the mobile version of my site. I can't remove it since it use resources from the desktop version of the site so if I remove it would disappear from the desktop version.

I tried to hide it using CSS by using this code,

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .HideMobile{
        display:none;
    }  
}
```

So, my question is. Is there any better way to do this? I'm trying to hide a PHP code from mobile platforms.

Comment: Are you saying that your media query code is not hiding the element?

Comment: Correct. I am supposed to div the content right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this PHP library http://mobiledetect.net

This will help you to detect different devices using which you can add your code conditionally.

Comment: I use this in pretty much all the sites I build.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [this](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) , works great disregarding display size , assuming your mobile version includes tablets ,ipads..etc.

usage:

as simple as including this snippet:

```
(function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
```

just call it on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to hide HTML Output, make a class in your css

```
.hide_mobile {
    display:block;
}
```

and say in your css, that on a special width this class should be set to display:none;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.hide_mobile {
    display:none;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to hide PHP output, not HTML.

Comment: You can't output PHP. When you want a dynamic solution ( a script which realize when the browser gets smaller ) you should work with javascript e.g. jQuery window width functions etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adopting a RESS approach. It is essentially a combination of responsive web design with a server component. The general logic here is as follows: requesting device is identified on server and based on some conditions that you set a certain set of resources is supplied. For a server detection software I recommend using solution from [51Degrees](https://51degrees.com).

So, suppose you have a div block on your website that you want to hide on all mobile devices. First you need to download the PHP detector from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fiftyone/). Your page would then have the following code:

**page.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'path/to/core/51Degrees.php';
require_once 'path/to/core/51Degrees_usage.php';
//Where path/to/core is path to 'core' directory of detector
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
$css_file = "desktop.css";

if ($_51d['IsMobile'] == TRUE)
{
$css_file = "mobile.css";
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=$css_file; ?>">
</head>
<body>
<div class="desktop_only">
<p>Lorem......</p>
</div>
</body>
```

**mobile.css**

```
.desktop_only
{
 display:none;
}
```

Now mobile devices won't see that div. The real benefit of this approach is in the ability to supply a different set of resources, based on device type and you don't have to place dozens of media-queries for every possible screen size. You might want to tweak the mobile design of your website to avoid wasting precious screen space of smartphones and tablets, or re-design the menu to avoid drop-down sections etc...

Another great thing about this approach is: if you ever need to conduct additional checks (i.e: supply different theme for Apple devices, or check if device supports HTML canvas etc...) they will be easy to integrate in to your current implementation.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

PHP is server side, has nothing to do with clients which request your data